# Find the "uncle" in binary tree - Python

Tags: python

my mission is to build a function which return the number of "uncles" in a given binary tree A node is an uncle only if his brother(the second child of his father) has children.
This is my code:
"

```
def uncle(root,count = None):
    if count is None:
        count = [0]
    a,b = 0,0
    if root.left:
        if root.left.left or root.left.right: 
            a = uncle(root.left)
            a = 1
    if root.right:
        if root.right.right or root.right.left:
            b = uncle(root.right)
            b = 1
    if b > 0:
        count[0] += 1
    if a > 0:
        count[0] += 1
    return count[0]
```

"
And this is the bin_tree class:
"

```
Class bin_tree():
    def __init__(self,data, left_child = None, right_child = None):
        self.data = data
        self.left = left_child
        self.right = right_child
```

"
My problem is this: 
When I switched the lines:
            a = uncle(root.left)
            a = 1
It didn't work(**meaning = the variable a has changed back its value to 0 for some reason**), and I absolutely doesn't know why..I thought it should have worked because
it doesn't matter if I call in recursion to the function first or say a = 1 firstly.
Can someone help me please?

Comment: If you have `a=1` followed by `a=uncle(...)`, the second line will overwrite the value of `a`.

Comment: but why? I don't return 'a'.. so why 'a' value is changing?

Comment: Because you are assigning a value to it. That's what `a = something` does.

Comment: but I assigned a = 1! not a = 0!

Comment: You assigned two different values. The first was 1, and the second was whatever `uncle` returned.

Comment: Also, you never call `uncle` with a `count` parameter, so you always initialize `count` to `[0]` at the top of `uncle`.

Comment: Thank you very much.Didn't notice that I used the same variable.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this but it should work. The code you wrote can be cut down a lot.

For starters you have count as a list when it doesn't really need to be.

Your a and b never get used so there is no point in assigning anything to them. That is probably why you get an error regardless of what value you give to a or b.

Then you don't need to check if a or b are greater than 1. You can just increment count when you find out there is another uncle in the tree.

However the main reason that it is not working is that everytime you call uncle you are not passing your new count. This means that it takes the default value of which you have given as None. This then causes the list to reset to [0]. Well actually a new list is been created which is different from the previous one even though they have the same name. So although you may think you are updating the same count, you are not. This is a scope problem.

```
def uncle(root,count=0):
    if root.left:
        if root.left.left or root.left.right: 
            count = uncle(root.left, count)
            count += 1
    if root.right:
        if root.right.right or root.right.left:
            count = uncle(root.right, count)
            count += 1
return count
```